# PostgreSQL Select random rows having given sum

Tags: postgresql

One of columns in my table is called difficulty and its data type is integer.
I need a select which choose a random number of rows having sum of this difficulty equal to some integer (let say 50). Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you require an exact sum, not just "equal to or greater than", then that's actually a moderately hard problem in the mathematical sense of "hard". I suggest looking up existing algorithms people have designed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely have to loop through all records to achieve that, so why don't you simply `SELECT difficulty FROM {YOUR_TABLE}` and do loops and checks in the code (Java, PHP, whatever you use)? It would be easier to implement and less "expensive" memory sake

Comment: This is the alternative I was thinking about. However, I thought it would have been faster to let the DB select it for me. Specially in a case when there are many rows in the table.

Comment: I understand your point, but you will still have to loop through all of those rows (multiple times!) to find ones that add up to 50, basically, you will have to use really complex query in order to retrieve less data. And if you need it several times - hell breaks loose. Just pull all data, store it to an array and re-use that array every time you need it.

Comment: I am heading your way. Thank you for your help.